# OdbcCommand with parameters doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, odbc

I have the next code:

```
public static List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string qry, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new OdbcCommand(qry, connection);
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I execute something like:

```
ExecuteQuery<MyClass>("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 1");
```

It returns all the correct data. But when I send this:

```
ExecuteQuery<MyClass>(
    "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = @Id", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@Id", 1 } });
```

doesn't return anything. I've tried with command.Parameters.Add but is the same history.

So, where is my error?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting the named parameter with a `?`, which I believe is what  `OdbcCommand` uses.

```
ExecuteQuery<MyClass>("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = ?",
                      new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@Id", 1 } });
```

Also, since a `Dictionary` doesn't guarantee order, you may want to replace that with a `List<T>` in the event you have more than one parameter. A list guarantees order.

I'd also suggest specifying the `OdbcType` and not just adding all your parameter values as objects. It has to infer the correct data type otherwise, and it may guess wrong. You could create a more permanent class... here I decided to just use a `Tuple<T,T,T>`.

```
public static List<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string qry, List<Tuple<string, OdbcType, object>> parameters = null)

...
...

foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter.Item1, parameter.Item2).Value = parameter.Item3;
}
```

Comment: I like your advice about the OdbcType, but my database provider could change in any second so it means that I need to use the most separate way possible